# Can the Firefox JavaScript JIT be disabled from a script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, jit

Our web site has a fairly complex JS app that fails with the latest Firefox 10 release. This is due to what appears to be a bug in the JS interpretor, making variables return NULL when they clearly aren't. This bug only occurs when the JIT compiler is active, not when it's disabled. We will report the bug to Mozilla and try to find a workaround.

*Is there a way to disable the JIT in Firefox for a specific script, from inside the script?*

Thank you.

Comment: That sounds counter intuitive, even if it was possible. In order to issue the command to disable JIT for a specific section of JS, from JS. You will need the compiler to parse the JS and that can only be done by JIT. Since the script is already parsed, enabling or disabling JIT on it, does not make sense.

Comment: It could be a proprietary attribute on the script tag, or on the html page.

Comment: I would recommend that you use some sort of browser version sniffing to dynamically replace the offending piece of JS or display a page with reduced feature until Mozilla issues a fix based on your bug report. I would also look into scenario where Mozilla says that this is not a bug, therefore I would I also look at workaround at my end.

Comment: It actually is possible to order around the compiler, as I understand it the interpreter parses the code first anyway. It appears that the JIT only kicks in for repeated or recurring procedures called more than a certain number of times. But I admit, I didn't research this enough.

Comment: The issue is visible on this web page http://www.english-attack.com/game/say-what?content=101477 It's an english learning game built on HTML5-ish features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer comes from Brian Hackett (:bhackett) at mozilla.org:

> Using **`with`** in a script will disable the JIT for that script, e.g. adding a **`with({}) {}`** to the top.

See it here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730004#c11

Great news. This does indeed work around the issue.

Thanks everyone! Mozilla rocks!

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel, there is no reliable way to do it.  You *may* be able to disable the JIT for particular functions by using some sort of features that the JIT doesn't support yet, but obviously the JIT folks try to minimize the set of circumstances that can trigger this...  There is no official "turn off the JIT" command.

On the other hand, once you file the bug the JS engine folks may be able to suggest a workaround on your end, depending on what's going on.

Please cc me (":bz") on the bug you file?

Comment: Hi Boris,  the issue is created at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=730004 There is a screen shot with the debugger where the issue is visible. I can provide more details, debug dumps, or you can try it out here http://www.english-attack.com/game/say-what?content=101477

Comment: I am sure the bug itself will be fixed sooner or later. In the meantime, do you know if there is a particular function that just happens to disable the JIT _today_? We are having a lot of trouble working around this problem. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll continue the discussion in Bugzilla and report here if I find a workaround.