# Reduction of a JavaScript object with numeric keys and float values causes unpredictable behaviour on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, floating-point, reduce

Consider the following two objects:

```
const ReductionMap = {
  '10': 10.5,
  '1000': 20.5,
}

const initialValues = {
  '10': 110,
  '1000': 120,
}
```

Using lodash v4.17.5 (here `_`), we reduce `initialValues` to a new object where each values has been reduced by the corresponding value in `ReductionMap`:

```
const reducedValues = _.reduce(
  initialValues,
  (acc, value, key) => ({
    ...acc,
    [key]: value - ReductionMap[key],
  }),
  {}
)
```

What we would expect to get here would be

```
{ '10': 99.5, '1000': 99.5 }
```

but in mobile Safari on **iOS 10.3.2** I am getting:

```
{
  '0': NaN,
  '1': NaN,
  '2': NaN,
  '3': NaN,
  '4': NaN,
  '5': NaN,
  '6': NaN,
  '7': NaN,
  '8': NaN,
  '9': NaN,
  '10': 99.5,
  '11': NaN,
  '12': NaN,
  '1000': 99.5,
}
```

Here are some observations:

- Changing the key `'10'` to `'20'` or `'100`' yields an object with keys from 0 up to key + 4 and then `'1000'`.
- Examples of combinations of keys that do work are `'999', '1000'`, `'900', '1000'` and `'2000', '1000'`.
- Rounding the calculated value to an integer produces valid results.

I created a [pen on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmOEpR?editors=0010#0) where you can try out this phenomena.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

---

*Note: I'm not looking for ways to get around this issue, only to understand why this is happening.*

Comment: [What version of LoDash are you using?](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1033)

Comment: Is working as expected!

Comment: @Pointy v4.17.5. I've added it to the question.

Comment: @Ele On what iOS version is it working for you?

Comment: @AlexanderWallin interesting. Well the description of the behavior from that linked Github bug (and the other one linked from in there) sure seem similar to what you're seeing. I can't see how that's anything but a platform bug.

Comment: [You might see if tricks to disable JIT for that piece of code make a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147026/disabling-jit-in-safari-6-to-workaround-severe-javascript-jit-bugs), at least as an experiment.